# When I switch to monthly/yearly billing, I get "NaN" as a text content.Otherwise, my JS code is running well.My code snippets are attached below

Tags: html, css

Can not fix the "Nan" issue.I wish to display real "$12" format for example, instead of to be displaying isNan.Any hint how to get this working?
I am not really sure which direction should I go.
Already tried changing strings like "$8.00" to "8" as a textContent property.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Interactive pricing component</title>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="title-section">
      <h1 class="main-title">Simple, traffic-based pricing</h1>
      <span class="title-span-1">Sign up for our 30-day trial. No credit card required.</span>
      </span>
      <img src="./images/pattern-circles.svg" alt="background image pattern" class="img-pattern">
    </div>

    <div class="card-section">
      <h2 class="views-title"><span>100K</span> Pageviews</h2>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="3" class="slider-range">
      </div>
      <div class="amount-container">
        <span class="price">$16.00</span>
        <span class="month"> /month</span>
      </div>

      <div class="billing-container">
        <div class="billing-month">
          <span class="monthly-billing-text">Monthly Billing</span>
          <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="input-range">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="billing-year">
          <span class="yearly-billing-text">Yearly Billing</span>
          <span class="yearly-discount">-25%</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="billing-benefits">
        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited websites</li>
          <li>100% data ownership</li>
          <li>Email reports</li>
        </ul>

        <button class="button-trial">
          Start my trial
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS code:

```
const range = document.querySelector('.slider-range');
const pageViews = document.querySelector('.views-title span');
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const switcher = document.querySelector('.switch');
const checkbox = document.querySelector('.switch input');
const period = document.querySelector('.month');


switcher.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        let priceInt = parseInt(price.textContent);
        price.textContent = `${(priceInt - (priceInt * 0.25)) * 12}`;

        period.textContent = `/year`;
    } else {
        period.textContent = `/month`;
    }
})


range.addEventListener("input", updatePrice);


function updatePrice() {
    if (range.value == 1) {
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            price.textContent = `${(8 - (8 * 0.25)) * 12}`;
        } else {
            price.textContent = "$8.00";
        }
        pageViews.textContent = "10K";
    }

    if (range.value == 2) {
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            price.textContent = "$108.00";
        } else {
            price.textContent = "$12.00";
        }
        pageViews.textContent = "50K";
    }

    if (range.value == 3) {
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            price.textContent = "$144.00";
        } else {
            price.textContent = "$16.00";
        }
        pageViews.textContent = "100K";
    }

    if (range.value == 4) {
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            price.textContent = "$216.00";
        } else {
            price.textContent = "$24.00";
        }
        pageViews.textContent = "500K";
    }

    if (range.value == 5) {
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            price.textContent = "$324.00";
        } else {
            price.textContent = "$36.00";
        }
        pageViews.textContent = "1M";
    }

}
```

Comment: probably because your `price.textContent` isn't an int (or contains non int characters like the dollar sign) so `parseInt` returns `NaN` - see example: https://jsfiddle.net/5we0v7y6/